# How to have different receipt messages on different donation pages

Tags: civicontribute, message-templates

I have different donation pages and want to have completely different receipt messages sent. You can set up a custom "intro" text for the thank you message, but the bulk of the mail comes from the same template, no matter the contribution page, so limited options to change that. Moreover, the template message used if recurring donation is no using the custom thank you "intro" text.

Is there a way to change what template to use on a per page basis?

Comment: I haven't done this so I won't post it as an answer yet, but i'd imagine you could edit the system workflow template with something like

{if $contributionPageId == "yourPageId"} Your custom messaging here {/if}

Answer (score 2):

I tried @Eli Lisseck's suggestion and it worked. 
You can have a different receipt message per page by using this logic
{if $contributionPageId == "yourPageId"}